# Does GOL Airlines Allow a personal Item in addition to a carry on?

Tags: airlines, hand-luggage

[Seat Guru says](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/GOL/baggage.php) GOL allows a personal item such as:

> Bag or backpack with personal items

They point to [this GOL page](https://www.voegol.com.br/en/information/travel-worry-free/checked-and-carry-on-baggage) for more information but I find nothing to substantiate that.

**Does GOL actually allow a Personal Item in addition to a carry-on?**

Comment: I've traveled on GOL *with* a personal item, but that's only anecdotal.

Comment: Is there any airline that prohibits a personal item when taking a carry on bag?

Comment: @Tom - That's a good question! I accidentally found one which causes me problems... plus there are tons of questions here asking the same for various airlines.

Comment: @Tom good question. Depends on the definition. Many European LCCs will only allow for a personal item if you purchase something extra: premium fare, premium seat, something.

Comment: @chx (and Itai too) - how about naming those airlines for people's benefit

Comment: @tom http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76936/4188

Comment: @chx - WizzAir, EasyJet, Transavia ... a much shorter, simpler answer, rather than links to a long thread to troll through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, Gol allows it and there is no specific restriction on its size and weight.**

This is part of a conversation I had with GOL (I had to first explain what I meant by personal item with example of a camera or laptop bag):

> GOL: I was checking and I see that you can take a little bag like the 
>   one with a camera with no problems additionally to the carry on bag
>
> Itai: Great. Are there any restrictions on the bag? Size or Weight?
>
> GOL: I don't see anyone, it only says little bag with personal items.